# How to make scroll visible

Tags: html, css

I have got a basic website and so far I have got a slide show with text under another div tag under it, but I am unable to scroll down and I don't know why.

I have tried googling for an answer, but I have had no luck on finding a solution.

CODE:

My CSS is here:

https://pastebin.com/uJMf5whM

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Galaxy Games</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/galaxygames.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/galaxygames.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1><a href="index">Galaxy Games</a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li id="active"><a href="index">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="games">Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="videos">Videos</a></li>
            <li><a href="newswire">Newswire</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.socialclub.galaxy-games.co.uk" target="_blank">Social Club</a></li>
            <li><a href="downloads">Downloads</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.galaxywarehouse.co.uk" target="_blank">Warehouse</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.support.galaxy-games.co.uk" target="_blank">Support</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <global-login ng-version="6.0.7">
        <link href="galaxy_games/users/css/global-login.css" rel="stylesheet"><!---->
        <div class="logged-out">
            <div>
                <a href="#" rel="nofollow" target="_self">Sign In</a> or
            </div>
            <div>
                <a class="sc" data-gtm-action="Join Social Club" data-gtm-category="Social Club" data-gtm-label="" href="#" target="_blank">Join Social Club</a>
            </div>
        </div><!---->
    </global-login>
</div>
</div>
<div class="info">
    <h1>Galaxy Games</h1>
    <h2>Home To The Great Unwashed Hordes</h2>
    <h3>EST Mcmxcviii</h3>
</div>
<div class="container show">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <a href="">
            <div class="icon icon-play"><!-- /c/ --></div>
            <img src="images/46e3dd55b6cc4f1df004cabd85cbaac6fc8e1218.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
            </a>
                <a class="official" href="">Official Website</a></button>
                <a class="buy" href="">Buy Now</a></button>
            </div>
        </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="">
            <div class="icon icon-play"><!-- /c/ --></div>
            <img src="images/black.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
            </a>
            <a class="official" href="">Official Website</a></button>
            <a class="buy" href="">Buy Now</a></button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="">
            <div class="icon icon-play"><!-- /c/ --></div>
            <img src="images/46e3dd55b6cc4f1df004cabd85cbaac6fc8e1218.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
            </a>
            <a class="official" href="">Official Website</a></button>
            <a class="buy" href="">Buy Now</a></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
</div>
    <div class="well">
        <h2 class="text-divider"><span>Test</span></h2>
    </div>
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vETUQ.jpg

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please share the complete HTML ?

Comment: @PR7 i have updated the above with complete HTML

Comment: there is some HTML missing in the end, the last div looks incomplete..

Comment: @PR7 What do you mean, because i have now completed the div at the end, but no change :/

Comment: in the snippet that you have added, at the end there is `<div class="container">`, i cannot see the closing of that div.

Comment: @PR7 I have update the above with my update code as there is not change :/

Comment: okay now i see the updated HTML, i'll take a look now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

main problem with **show** class.
you not need "*position: fixed*" in **.show** class or not needs in whole class **.show** with **.container** class!

Comment: Nothing changed